# How to vertically align deeply nested labels, which are randomly interleved?

Tags: css

I try to align two kinds of columns, which are interleaved by random content, but without specifying the width.

```css
label::after {
  content: ':';
  margin-right: 1ch;
}
label.s {
  background-color: #AAF;
}
label.l {
  background-color: #AFA;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>lore ipsum</div>
  <form>
    <label class="s">M</label>short
  </form>
  <div>lore ipsum</div>
  <form>
    <label class="s">MMM</label>short
  </form>
  <div>lore ipsum</div>
  <form>
    <label class="l">MMMMMMMMMM M</label>long
  </form>
  <div>lore ipsum</div>
  <form>
    <label class="s">MMMMM</label>short
  </form>
  <div>lore ipsum</div>
  <form>
    <label class="l">MMMMMMMMMM MMM</label>long
  </form>
  <div>lore ipsum</div>
  <form>
    <label class="l">MMMMMMMMMM MMMMM</label>long
  </form>
  <div>lore ipsum</div>
</article>
```

My aim is to vertically align the "short" strings in one column and the "long" strings in another column.

Is this possible just with CSS?

Comment: why all those forms?

Comment: @TemaniAfif just a placeholder to illustrate nesting.

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected result?